# DNN Search Automatic Reindexing

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-module

Is there a way in DNN 6.0 to automatically reindex the search results. Because unless we click on host->Search Admin->Reindex Content some of the recently uploaded content would not appear in search results until the content is manually reindexed. I wish to know if there is a way to automate this process so that it'll happen on a daily basis.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "search engine schedule" should handle this for you. It's possible that the schedule is disabled or needs to be run more frequently, check under Host > schedule.

Comment: Appreciate the answer thanks. In the schedule I checked the Search Engine Scheduler for every 30 minutes.